# how to show contents of any user at a specific class in android cloud backened app using parse

Tags: android, cloud, backend, posts

I have a cloud backened app using parse, in which there is login and sign up option, user can sign up and add contents to it, I want to ask that how can i show all the contents of all registered users in a specific class, such that each user who sign up can see all the contents posted by any user, but only the registered user can make the changes in their posted contents

At present when a new user sign up and login to account it does not shows the contents posts of other users, only their own posts are being shown.

I am adding the code snipped for fetching the contents

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");
    /*query.whereEqualTo("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);*/

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> postList, ParseException e) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            if (e == null) {

                // If there are results, update the list of posts
                // and notify the adapter
                posts.clear();
                for (ParseObject post : postList) {
                    Note note = new Note(post.getObjectId(), post
                            .getString("title"), post.getString("content"));
                    posts.add(note);
                }
                ((ArrayAdapter<Note>) getListAdapter())
                        .notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {

                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you the code to fetch all entries of a particular table on Parse. You can use this code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClass");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
 public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
     if (e == null) {
         objectsWereRetrievedSuccessfully(objects);
     } else {
         objectRetrievalFailed();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: where you want to get the list of posts and show it on screen

Comment: thats great, thank you very much for your help,  

One more thing I would like to ask that whether there is any option , such that only the contents uploaded by the current user should be editable, else the contents uploaded by others should only be visible but not editable..

at present all the contents of all users are shown, and also all are editable, I want that the other users contents should be read only...

Thanks for your great help

Comment: I have added the code for fetching the items, plz help that how the editable and non editable work can be performed on it, which i have asked you above..

Comment: You can match the user id of every object with the current user id if that matches that post will be editable otherwise not. And please accept the answer if you have got what you asked,